# Natural Numbers Object and the Axiom of Infinity

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, natural-numbers

It is well known (if you're a topos-theorist, you will call it the *definition*), that the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ together with the zero constant $0$ and the successor function $1\xrightarrow{\ 0\ }\mathbb{N}\xrightarrow{+1}\mathbb{N}$ are initial in the category of such diagrams of sets $1\longrightarrow X\longrightarrow X$ (this is known as the principle of *inductive definition*).

Suppose we work in some class theory like NBG.

> Is it true that the natural numbers are still initial in the (meta-)category of such diagrams of classes? Or in set-theoretical terms, does inductive definition work for classes?

Originally, I was thinking about the following: Suppose we replace the classical [Axiom of Infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity) by the

**Axiom of an NNO:** There exists a [Natural Numbers Object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object) in $\mathbf{Set}$.

> Can I show that finite cardinals form a set by recursively defining a function $\mathbb{N}\xrightarrow{\ \ f\ \ }(\text{Class of all Sets})$ by $f(0)=\emptyset$ and $f(n+1)=f(n)\cup\{f(n)\}$ and then applying the Axiom of replacement?

Comment: What is the meaning of 'meta-category'?

Comment: @tetori Basically something which works like a category but might be too large to fit in somebody's preferred definition of a category. I borrowed the term from CWM: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metacategory

Comment: I guess, yes, $\Bbb N$ remains the natural number object in the metacategory ${\bf Class}$ of classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by assuming $\omega$ is the smallest set containing $\emptyset$ and closed under the operation $x \mapsto x \cup \{ x \}$. (Such a thing is guaranteed to exist in ZFC and NBG.) We want to show that $\omega$ is an NNO in the category of classes.

Let $X$ be a class, let $x_0 \in X$, and let $F : X \to X$ be a class-function. By the axiom of class comprehension, we may form the class $A$ of all partial functions $f : \omega \to X$ such that $f (\emptyset) = x_0$ and $f (x \cup \{ x \}) = F (f (x))$. (Of course, by ‘partial function’ I mean a set of pairs satisfying the obvious conditions.) It is non-empty: the partial function $\{ (\emptyset, x_0) \}$ is a member of $A$. Moreover, by ordinary induction, we can show that, for every $n \in \omega$, there is $f \in A$ with $(n, x_n) \in f$ for some $x_n \in X$; moreover, since $F$ is functional, for every $n \in \omega$, there is a unique $x_n \in X$ such that $(n, x_n) \in f$ for all $f \in A$ such that $(n, x) \in f$ for some $x \in X$. This defines a class-function $\omega \to X$ (by class comprehension), so we are done.

It appears to me that the above goes through for ZFC, provided we interpret "class" and "class comprehension" correctly.